# How to interpret this json decoded array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I interpret this JSON decoded array?  It seems like more of a complex array than I'm accustomed to dealing with so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
array(1){
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (11){
        ["id"]=> string(5) "72324"
        ["txid"]=> string(64) "**bitcoin_tx_id**"
        ["from"]=> string(34) "**bitcoin_address**"
        ["to"]=> string(20) "email@somewhere.com"
        ["amount"]=> int(10000000)
        ["amount_sent"]=> int(0)
        ["note"]=> string(0) ""
        ["time"]=> float(1379742767000)
        ["to_addr"]=> string(34) "**bitcoin_address**"
        ["read"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["balance"]=> string(10) "0.10000000"
    }
}
```

Comment: `<pre>` tag is your friend. Try `echo '<pre>',print_r($array),'</pre>'` -- that'll produce a more readable output of your array. Please edit the question and update the question :)

Comment: You can also try `var_dump($array)` :-)

Comment: @AmalMurali Or, just view the source...

Comment: It returned this:

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 72324
            [txid] => 46b0dbd8ccf60bcb1eeb6c57f7da54667336ed4cdd522eb4625822d721f39841
            [from] => 1ANt6XDbytAUM6VSwvxYJsPzjeB6owHT8V
            [to] => gigadice@hotmail.com
            [amount] => 10000000
            [amount_sent] => 0
            [note] => 
            [time] => 1379742767000
            [to_addr] => 1GE8G5mYQSs5MP4RcnXdYdDtESrJTCof2P
            [read] => 1
            [balance] => 0.10000000
        )

)
1

Comment: How can I echo the id in the array though?

Comment: It's an array containing one element, an object.  That object contains properties.  So, `$array[0]->id` is `72324`.

Comment: I removed the bitcoin addresses and txid.  I don't think those need to be displayed here.

Comment: Either force the decode to be an associative array with the second parameter of `json_decode`, or use the object as intended: `$array[0]->id;`

Comment: try using this
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>

Comment: @AmalMurali: `print_r` will *print* the data for you.  You need to pass `TRUE` as the 2nd parameter to have it return a string.

Comment: @anandkumar: What does that have to do with this question?

Comment: @RocketHazmat there is a way to decode the json using json_encode($arr); then it ll become normal json format, it can be interpreted very easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning an array of objects, it looks like you're just dumping it to stdout. Toss the output from [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) inside a variable and you may access it like this:

```
$decoded = json_decode($data);

foreach($decoded as $obj) {
   echo "ID: " . $obj->id . ', ';
   echo "TXID: " . $obj->txid . ', ';
   echo "From: " . $obj->from . ', ';
   echo "To: " . $obj->to. ', ';
   // ...

   echo "<br>";
}
```

If you want `json_decode()` to return an associative array (which most people are used to), simply set the second parameter to `true`.